# PHP: Parse and split key and value in array

Tags: php, arrays

I have this kind of array

```
array(1) { 
    ["key,language,text"] => "home,es,casa" 
}
```

Is it possible to parse it and split it to have

```
array(3) { 
    ['key'] => "home" ,
    ['language'] => "es" ,
    ['text'] => "casa" 
}
```

My actual solution is to do the following but I'm pretty sure that I can find a better approach

```
$test = explode(',', $my_array['key,language,text']);
$my_array['key'] = $test[0];
$my_array['language'] = $test[1];
$my_array['text'] = $test[2];
```

Comment: What if there's mismatch within key and values?

Comment: @NarendrasinghSisodia, there are validation rules before this. So the values should be in the correct order

Answer (score 1):

You can use [array_combine](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) to create an array from an array of keys and values, providing the length of each is equal, it will return false if there is a mismatch.

```
foreach($array as $keys_str => $values_str) {
    $keys = explode(",", $keys_str);
    $values = explode(",", $values_str);
    $kv_array = array_combine($keys, $values);
}
```

`$kv_array` would be in the format you're after.

Answer (score 0):

Give it a try..

```
$arr = array("key,language,text" => "home,es,casa");

$val = explode(",", $arr[key($arr)]);
foreach(explode(",", key($arr)) as $k => $key){
    $data[$key] = $val[$k];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have an array with only 1 entry:

```
$a = ["key,language,text" => "home,es,casa"];
```

you could use [reset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php) which will return the value of the first array element and [key](http://php.net/key) which will return the key of the array element that's currently being pointed to by the internal pointer.

Then use explode and use a comma as the delimiter and use [array_combine](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) using the arrays from explode for the keys and the values to create the result.

```
$result = array_combine(explode(',', key($a)), explode(',', reset($a)));
print_r($result);
```

That will give you:

```
array(3) {
  ["key"]=>
  string(4) "home"
  ["language"]=>
  string(2) "es"
  ["text"]=>
  string(4) "casa"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This best solution for you :

```
//this your problem
$array = [
"key,language,text" => "home,es,casa",
"key,language,text" => "home1,es1,casa1"
];
$colms_tmp = 0;
//this your solution, foreach all
foreach($array as $key => $val){
   //split your value
   $values = explode(",",$val);
   //foreach the key (WITH COLMNS), $colm is number of key after explode
   foreach(explode(",",$key) as $colm => $the_key){
      $result[$colms_tmp][$the_key] = $values[$colm];
   }
   $colms_tmp++;
}
```

i haven't try it, but i think this can help you.